# Where is the current place to go to report bugs/issues?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-365-operations

I know there is https://experience.dynamics.com for Ideas and there is a place where you can file support ticket on LCS. But what if when I am not working on any customer project and I want to report some bugs related to Visual Studio or D365 development?

Comment: Do you have access to yammer group? https://www.yammer.com/dynamicsaxfeedbackprograms/#/home

Comment: Also since Microsoft Connect is retired, you can find more resources and information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/collaborate/connect-redirect